# Error in model.frame.default(form = classvariable ~ ., data = trainingDataset, : variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Length')

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I've tried to look at similar questions but can't figure out my problem.

I was already able to complete my analysis with random forest (using caret), tuning parameters separately. Now I'm trying to create a function that will perform my analysis all at once.

I created a function with two inputs, the dataset, and variable to be classified.
For now I'm using the iris dataset for simplicity.

```
RF <- function(data, classvariable) {

               # Best mtry
               trControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10,           
                                         search = "grid")
               set.seed(1234)
               tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1: 3))
               RF_mtry <- train(classvariable ~.,
                                data = dataset,
                                method = "rf",
                                metric = "Accuracy",
                                tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                                trControl = trControl,
                                importance = TRUE,
                                ntree = 100)
                  print(RF_mtry)

               mtry = 0
               for (i in 1:nrow(RF_mtry$results)) {
                    if (RF_mtry$results[i,2] > mtry) mtry <-                    
                                                     RF_mtry$results[i,2]
               }
               trial_mtry <- c(1:3)
               best_mtry <- trial_mtry[i]
               best_mtry
}
```

Once I run the function

```
 RF(data = iris, classvariable = Species)
```

I get the error

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Tried running the code without putting it in a function, so i wrote directly iris instead of dataset and Species instead of classvariable, and it works.

previously I was getting the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(form = classvariable ~ ., data = trainingDataset,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Sepal.Length')
```

Anybody have an idea why it does not work?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you reduce the code to a minimal reproducible example? Data preprocessing (imputation in this case) should be performed within resampling and not prior to it to prevent data leakage.

Comment: yup already tried that. Removed both imputation and train and test division. Still doesn't work. Now I'm getting a ` Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected ` error

Comment: found the errors. 
1. classvariable when called in the function needs to be in " "
2. class variable needs to be reassigned
`n <- which(colnames(dataset) == classvariable)    
          colnames(dataset)[n] <- "classvariable"`
3. added the libraries with require()